# Objective c, Memory management of instance members

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am confuzed by the memory management of instance members. I have a class with a ivar:

```
DetailedResultsTableViewController *detailedResultsTableViewController;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailedResultsTableViewController *detailedResultsTableViewController;
```

in the .m file:

```
@synthesize detailedResultsTableViewController;
```

and

```
[detailedResultsTableViewController release];
```

When I initial this variable:

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

I tested the retaincount right after this init and it is 2 !!! if i release it in the end of the function it will fall for not allocated object. What am I doing wrong? how should I initial this type of variable?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should not look at the retaincount, it not really reliable.

Second your property is set to retain. So when you assign some thing to it, it will increase the reatincount. As will `alloc`.

Doing it like this you are leaking:

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

you should do:

```
DetailedResultsMapViewController *vc = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil];
self.detailedResultsMapViewController =vc;
[vc release], vc= nil;
```

Or use Autorelease:

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That was what I was looking for! Why should I use the `vc= nil;`? Is it mandatory?

Comment: No, it more a convention. You call methods on `nil` objects without you app crashing. Some interesting reading about nilling: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/dealloc.html

Comment: It's just a "nice thing". It can prevent problems if you then go on to send messages to vc further down your code, but you'd just have things not working rather than crashes of your app. See my answer for details of what is going on in the background which might help you understand properties a bit more.

Comment: Question: What if ARC was used?  Then your first code segment is acceptable?  Since auto release is no allowed?

Answer (score 4):

Using the property and synthesize gives you a new method.  In this instance, you would have a new set and get method for the `detailedResultsTableViewController`.  This is generated for you when you compile (ie there is no code that you have to add)

This set method will be

```
- (void)setDetailedResultsTableViewController:(DetailedResultsTableViewController *)c 
{
    if (detailedResultsTableViewController != nil) 
    {
        [detailedResultsTableViewController release];
        detailedResultsTableViewController = nil;
    }
    detailedResultsTableViewController = [c retain];
}
```

So, when you call

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] init...];
```

What you are actually calling is

```
[self setDetailedResultsMapViewController:[[DetailedResultsMapViewControler...]]];
```

And so you are actually doing two retains.  One where you are calling alloc...init. and then the other because you are implicitly calling the setDetailedResultsMapViewController which will then do a retain as well.

If you are using properties, you would use

```
DetailedResultsTableViewController *d = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] init...]
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = d;
[d release];
```

The benefit of this is that you don't have to remember to release the old object before assigning the new as the synthesized method does that for you.  You can also just do

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = nil;
```

in your dealloc method and you won't have to worry if you have already released it elsewhere.

This is useful to know because you can override the set method by manually entering the code which allows you to do things when the objects are set.

Comment: Oops I got sidetracked there... If ARC was used, Then will your second code segnment correct.  Since Autorelease is allowed under ARC?  Btw, I still prefer your next to last segnment way.

Comment: This isn't really about auto-releasing. This is to explain what happens "behind the scenes" by the compiler when you use `@property` and `@synthesize` in your code. This, I think, helps massively to understand potential problems with over-retaining or over-releasing in your code. I've seen a lot of people who don't understand what is happening and they either find it difficult to understand when to use retain and when not to when using properties.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing **two** things wrong.

**Firstly:**

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

should be:

```
self.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

because you are using `self.…` you are using the memory management semantic of the property, which in this case is `retain` so it is retained again.

**Secondly:**

You've used `retainCount`. Which has no use whatsoever in debugging memory management.

If you want to know why this is wrong look at the other answers regarding retainCount right here on Stack Overflow, or read @bbum's [fuller description](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/) of why you shouldn't use it.

You broke the memory management rules by not releasing something you owned. This alone is enough to find the problem in your code. In fact, I'm surprised that the static analyser didn't pick up this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you declare a property as `retain`, and you refer to it using self.myiVar it will use the setter, and the setter will retain the object. Additionally because you are using alloc on the object, that will also increase the retain count to 2, bringing the retain count to 2.

As a note I would not trust the retainCount too much, it gives incorrect results sometimes, however it is correct this time.

Here are some options to avoid it having a retain count of 2:

```
//Refer to it with using the setter
detailedResultsMapViewController = [[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil];

//Autorelease it after alloc
detailedResultsMapViewController = [[[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a retained property it increments the retain count on any self.myProperty =

Alloc also increments the retain count.   So in your case the retain count is 2.

There a couple approaches.

1. You could include an autorelease in your init alloc statement
2. Create a temporary variable while you set up your instance then when you are done set your property to it and release the temp.
3. Drop the self. for this assignment.  The catch here is if you have a custom setMyVariable: function then it will not get called without the self.
4. Use ARC and you don't have to worry about any of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@interface` is correct, but your implementation slightly wrong:

```
@implmentation MyClass

//It's good practice to explicitly state the a variable name for this property to use 
//The common approach is to use the property name with a leading underscore
//This prevents accidentally accessing the ivar within the class instead of using the     accessor methods. You should only access the ivar directly within the accessor methods (which in these case are being created for you by  @synthesize), in the designate init method and dealloc
@synthesize detailedResultsTableViewController = _detailedResultsTableViewController;

-(void)dealloc
{
//...
    [_detailedResultsTableViewController release];
//...
}

@end
```

When accessing the property:

```
myClass.detailedResultsMapViewController = [[[DetailedResultsMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedResultsMapViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

The code that is setting the method does not 'own' the new value therefore it must `autorelease`.