# Memory leak in a class with 3 NSMutableArrays. Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak with instruments in a class that I've created. This is the class:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface RDItem : NSObject {

}
@property int Id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nombre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thumbnailPush;
@property int defaultColorId;
@property int idTema;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedFrame;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mergedFrame;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *colors;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *textures;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *styles;

-(void)initialize;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "RDItem.h"


@implementation RDItem
@synthesize Id;
@synthesize nombre;
@synthesize thumbnail;
@synthesize thumbnailPush;
@synthesize defaultColorId;
@synthesize idTema;
@synthesize selectedFrame;
@synthesize mergedFrame;

@synthesize colors;
@synthesize textures;
@synthesize styles;

-(void)initialize
{
    colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    textures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    styles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [colors release];
    [textures release];
    [styles release];
}
@end
```

This class have 3 NSMutableArray where I'll store data. In order to prepare and initialice this class, I've developed the method initialize where the 3 arrays are created. In dealloc are released.

The leaks tool detects a leak each time this class is used because the initialize method.

Which is the best way to initialize these arrays?

Thanks.

EDIT

Hi I've solved the leak with RDItem but now appears another lear in a very similar class:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RDTema : NSObject {

}
@property int Id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *idManifest;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *idTema;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nombre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thumbnailPush;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *colors;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *textures;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *styles;

-(void)initialize;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "RDTema.h"


@implementation RDTema
@synthesize Id;
@synthesize idManifest;
@synthesize idTema;
@synthesize nombre;
@synthesize thumbnail;
@synthesize thumbnailPush;

@synthesize items;

@synthesize colors;
@synthesize textures;
@synthesize styles;

-(void)initialize
{
    /*
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.textures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.styles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     */

    self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.colors = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.textures = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.styles = [NSMutableArray array];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [idManifest release];
    [idTema release];
    [nombre release];
    [thumbnail release];
    [thumbnailPush release];

    [items release];
    [colors release];
    [textures release];
    [styles release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now I'm getting a leak in these lines:

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
self.colors = [NSMutableArray array];
self.textures = [NSMutableArray array];
self.styles = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Anyone can explain why is happening in this class and not in RDItem class now? Are the same :(

Thanks.

Comment: though the implementation does not seems to create a real memory leak with the line of code you have shared. though I have shared a better implementation.

Comment: No leaks in your code. But I have few questions: 1) How many times you call "initialize" method? 2) Do you release objects which were inserted into mutable arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better suggested implementation

```
-(void)initialize
{
    self.colors = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.textures = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.styles = [NSMutableArray array];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.colors = nil;
    self.textures = nil;
    self.styles = nil;
}
```

Comment: And don't forget `[super dealloc];`.

Comment: This is the solution applied :) Thanks!

Comment: @samfisher , can you please explain why you chose to set them as `nil` instead of `release`ing them?, i thought `nil` was set only for IBOutlets in `viewDidUnload`.Edit: Sorry my mistake , i thought you were `alloc`ing them

Comment: @iNoob, self.object = nil calls your setter, which will release the old value, set the member to nil

Comment: See here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576593/objective-c-memory-management-of-instance-members/8576760#8576760) for a description of what is happening "behind the scenes" when you use `@property` and `@synthesize`. Might help you understand the concepts a bit more

Comment: @NickBull thanks for that, so is it a good practice to set even the arrays,dictionaries,strings etc. as `nil` in `dealloc` each time ? Sorry if i'm not supposed to ask questions in this manner.

Comment: @iNoob in `dealloc`, if you put `self.something = nil`, then that is "shorthand" for writing `[something release]` which you have to do otherwise you will start leaking. Read the Apple docs (or Wikipedia) on reference counting in Objective-C for more.

Comment: @NickBull Ok great thanks. I thought `self.x=nil` and `[x release]` were different.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are getting the leak because you call your initialize message more than once and you are not releasing the variables.

Normally, you should use setters or getters to access your ivars, so the appropiate operations are called (like the release message before assigning a new value on setter).

And remember to call [super dealloc] as the last instruction for your dealloc ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code where you are initialising the RDItem i can't say for sure.

But i expect that you are not releasing your previous RDItem before creating your new one. So post the code where you are creating your RDItems so we can say for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think, that leak are in arrays filling code, not init. For example, you alloc and init some NSString and put it in your NSMutable array without release or autorelease it. Or something like this. Make shure that you filling your arrays right way.

Answer (score -1):

Just `init` them when you need it. Calling `alloc` and `init` holds to arrays whose content is `nil`. Call `alloc` `initWithObjects:` and fill the arrays.