# iOS - Why my NSURL isn't retained in the init method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsurl

I'm creating a new UIViewController with 2 properties :

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *title;
```

and synthetised :

```
@synthesize url = _url;
@synthesize title = _title;
```

in my custom init method i'm not using the setter like the Memory Management Guide says but when I need to use the properties in the viewDidLoad, the url seems empty, the title doesn't

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)titleTemp
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"navigatorViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _url = url;
        _title = titleTemp;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     [_titreBarButtonItem setTitle:_title];

     NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:_url];
    [_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [urlRequest release];
}
```

I can see my title but my web view is blank.
If I use self.url in the init, it's working !

Do you have an idea ?

PS : Here's how I call my init  :

```
NSString *urlString = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"infos" ofType:@"html"] copy];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:urlString];
[urlString release];
navigatorViewController *navigatorVC = [[navigatorViewController alloc] initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Infos"];
[url release];
[self presentViewController:navigatorVC animated:YES completion:nil];
[navigatorVC release];
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using `@synthesize`, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576593/objective-c-memory-management-of-instance-members/8576760#8576760) for an overview of what is happening "in the background". Also make sure you understand the memory management in objective-c with `retain`, `release` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must retain the URL either using :

```
self.url = url;
```

in the init method or call the retain after assigning the url in the init method like this.

```
_url = url;
[_url retain];
```

Comment: And after you call the retain don't forget to call the release on the self.url in the dealloc.

Answer (score 4):

you are setting up the properties as retain, but this only applies if you use the synthesized getters. By setting the value directly on the ivar, you are bypassing this and the value is not being retained

you should be doing (probably not a great way when you already have setters):

```
_url = [url retain];
```

or better:

```
self.url = url;
```

or even better as matt said in the comments: use ARC

Comment: Adding to this, this is where ARC is a joy to work with because it will add a retain for you when doing `_url = url`. So you can bypass your setter if you want to and get the benefit of proper memory management as well.

Comment: good point @mattjgalloway, so the answer here is really: do the retain yourself, use the setter, or use ARC

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference (for what you *hold*) using `copy` or `retain`:

```
_url = [url copy];
_title = [titleTemp copy];
```

or

```
_url = [url retain];
_title = [titleTemp retain];
```

Comment: @Dave title is an `NSString` literal - it is immortal

Answer (score 1):

Well if you write a custom `init` method you need to do the retain your self:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)titleTemp
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"navigatorViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _url = [url retain];
        _title = [titleTemp retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

That it worked with title is just that the variable is probably released later then the `NSURL` passes in the init method.