# xcode empty var that was set properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am getting an empty var value when accessing to it. That var was properly overwrite.

"name1" is declared at .h like:

```
NSString *nomTab1;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nomTab1;
```

in .m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray alloc];

    nomTab1 = [NSString alloc];
```

also is synthezided and set properly during function execution. However, when I try to acces to it from another function (same controller), has an empty value. Seems to be a basic issue but not working... Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you set the value before accessing it?

Comment: Not enough info available in your question. Post your initialization code.

Comment: yes, was already allocated. Still not working

Comment: It's allocated but not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't retaining nomTab1. You say you have synthesized it, but you aren't then using `self.nomTab1 = ...` so the value isn't being retained.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576593/objective-c-memory-management-of-instance-members/8576760#8576760) for an explanation of synthesize and properites.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize it. You should have an init method in your class that looks like the following:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // do something
        self.nomTab1 = [NSString string];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never have a naked alloc in your code. You should alloc and init together, like this:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:..];
nomTab1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithSomeValue:...];
```

NSArrays and NStrings are immutable so they don't have any value until they've been initialised (which is probably why they seem empty when you access them), and they can't be changed once they've been initialised.

If you're planning to set their values later, either set them to nil and set them to an object once you know what they are, or use NSMutableArray and NSMutableString, which can be modified after they've been created.