# About NSObject release

Tags: ios, nsstring

Sorry about my english...

**in ".h" file**

```
NSString *_name;
```

**in ".m" file**

```
-(id)init{

.....

_name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hadrian"];

.....

}
```

and a function use to change the value of _name like this :

```
-(void) changeName:(NSString *)name{

    //No 1:

    _name = [name copy];

    //No 2:

    if(_name) [_name release];

    _name = [name copy];

}
```

No 1 cause leak? how to write this function standard?

Comment: Why not to use @property / @synthesize?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions...**

- **@property and @synthesize :** If you use @property / @synthesize, getter/setters are handled by 
  them. You don't need to handle it. (Use features instead of having long
  code)

  Look also answer from [Inject IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722366/difference-between-using-properties-and-not-for-accessing-ivars)

  > - Properties enforce access restrictions (such as readonly)
  > - Properties enforce memory management policy (retain, assign)
  > - Properties are (rarely) used as part of a thread safety strategy    (atomic)
  > - Properties provide the opportunity to transparently implement custom    setters and getters.
  > - Having a single way to access instance variables increases code    readability.
- **Naming Conventions :** Avoid _ prefixed to variable name to avoid conflicts with auto-generated accessor. Or else have synthesize as
  shown and explained at this [link by Kelan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work)
- **Leaks :** You own the object when you alloc an object, or create a copy. This means you're given the object with a retain count of 1(not
  autoreleased). You are responsible and you should release it when you
  have used that object.