# Why can I not initialise my variable without using self

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following variable defined:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arraySpeechSentences;
```

And I am trying to initialise it in the following way:

```
// Set the array of sentences to the stored array
NSMutableArray *speechSentences = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tempDict objectForKey:key]];
arraySpeechSentences = speechSentences;
[speechSentences release];
```

When I try to call [arraySpeechSentences count] the application crashes. However, if I set the variable in the following way:

```
// Set the array of sentences to the stored array
NSMutableArray *speechSentences = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tempDict objectForKey:key]];
self.arraySpeechSentences = speechSentences;
[speechSentences release];
```

I can call [arraySpeechSentences count] perfectly fine. I was under the impression that if you use self. it simply checks to see if variable is already set, and if so it will release the object before assigning it the new value. Have I got this wrong, and if so when should I be using self. to set values?

Thanks for any help,
Elliott

Comment: Always use self.propertyName when working with properties. And nil them the same way in dealloc.

Comment: The confusion may already arise in the first line of your question: When you use `@property` you don't declare a variable, but a property. Hence the need for `self`, which is needed for all property access within the instance itself.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea Unless you are overriding the setXXX method in which case you should be accessing the underlying instance variable (and handling the retain yourself too)

Comment: Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576593/objective-c-memory-management-of-instance-members/8576760#8576760) to a previous question which may help you understand `@property` and `@synthesize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give a detail answer for this.

First when you use `@property/@synthesize` directive you create getter and setter methods around a variable.

In your case, the variable is called `arraySpeechSentences` (the compiler will create the variable for you) and you can access these methods (setters and getters) with `self.`.

```
self.arraySpeechSentences = // something
```

is the same as

```
[self setArraySpeechSentences:something]; // setter
```

And

```
NSMutableArray* something = self.arraySpeechSentences;
```

is equal to

```
NSMutableArray* something = [self arraySpeechSentences]; // getter
```

In the first snippet of code

```
NSMutableArray *speechSentences = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tempDict objectForKey:key]];
arraySpeechSentences = speechSentences;
```

`arraySpeechSentences` points to the same object `speechSentences` points to. But when you do `[speechSentences release]` you dealloc that object and now `arraySpeechSentences` is a dangling pointer. You receive a message sent to a deallocated instance I suppose. Try to enable Zombie to see it.

Speaking in terms of retain count, the array has a retain count of 1 when you do `alloc-init`.
But when you `release` it, the retain count goes to zero, the object doesn't exist anymore and you have a crash when you try to access `arraySpeechSentences`.

Instead, when you deal with properties, the policy applied to a variable is important. Since the property use a `retain` policy, when you set an object

```
self.arraySpeechSentences = // something
```

the retain count for the referenced object is increased. Under the hood, saying `self.arraySpeechSentences = // something` is equal to call the setter like

```
- (void)setArraySpeechSentences:(NSMutableArray*)newValue
{
    // pseudo code here...
    if(newValue != arraySpeechSentences) {

       [arraySpeechSentences release];
       arraySpeechSentences = [newValue retain]; 
    }
}
```

The second snippet work since the retain count for your object is one when you do `alloc-init`, becomes two when you call `self.arraySpeechSentences =` and returns to one when you do the release. This time, the object is maintained alive since it has a retain count of 1.

If you have a property with a `retain` or `copy` policy, don't forget to release the object in `dealloc` like, otherwise you can have leaks.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [arraySpeechSentences release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

To understand how Memory works I suggest to read [MemoryManagement Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

*P.S.* Starting from iOS 5 there is a new compiler feature, called **ARC** (Automatic Reference Counting), that allows you to forget about `retain/release` calls. In addition, since it forces you to think in terms of object graphs, I suggest you to take a look into.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, it makes so much more sense now. I thought that the retain on the variables declaration automatically retained any object it was set to point too.

Answer (score 7):

Using a setter (like `self.foo = ...` or `[self setFoo:...]`) does release the old value but it also *retains the new value*, which is needed in the example you give.

The issue is that you're alloc and init'ing your array, and then releasing it. This indicates you no longer need it. So, you should either use the setter (usually preferable) or don't release your array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense now. Although you are top rated I gave the answer to Flex for the amount of detail but I appreciate the help!

Comment: You're quite welcome! He certainly included a *lot* of detail. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using ARC, you should type

```
arraySpeechSentences = [speechSentences retain];
```

because you're accessing the instance variable directly, which means the value of the instance variable `arraySpeechSentences` will be the address of the `speechSentence` object, which you just released, so which is an invalid pointer. The semantic you declared in the property doesn't have an effect on the instance variable itself.

When you type `self.arraySpeechSentences`, you're actually using a shortcut for the setter `[self setArraySpeechSentences:speechSentences]`, which actually *retains* the value passed as parameter (if you synthesized the property, it is retained because you specified `retain` in the property declaration; if you wrote the accessor yourself, it is your job to ensure you retained the value).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I made the mistake of thinking that the retain in the declaration did this automatically.